# How to convert KMZ geometry collection to SHP

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, kmz

I try to open and convert to shape a KMZ with Qgis, but impossible !
When I open it, I have this :

[image]

I select "Vigne" with 35 entities then OK. But there isn't entity displayed. In layer panel I have this weird icon.

[image]

So I decide to save it in shape, maybe it will work... But Qgis return me this message :

[image]

Somebody have an idea, how to read and convert this kind of KMZ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using ogr2ogr from the command line, for example:

```
ogr2ogr -nlt POLYGON -explodecollections -skipfailures shapefile.shp mykmlfile.kml
```

and -POINT or -LINESTRING for other geometry types
I'm not sure if this works with kmz files as well, so ypur might haveto unzip your kmz first.

this is where I got the general idea: [KML to Shapefile using GDAL (LIBKML) - MultiGeometry data not transforming](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76497/kml-to-shapefile-using-gdal-libkml-multigeometry-data-not-transforming)